# My bash script locks file when Java tries to read it

Tags: linux, bash, java, file-management, file-permissions

I have a bash script in Linux (CentOS) that redirects output to a file. It takes a few minutes to run:

```
./myBashScript.sh >> file.csv
```

I have a java application that tries to **read** the file (only read) for further processing:

```
    File file = new File("file.csv");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                // do something...
            }
```

These processes are on `Crontab`. It works all fine, but apparently whenever the bash script is redirecting the output to the file, the Java app can not read it. The logs shows `"File not found"` exception!

Is the file locked?! How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try/catch and retry... The lock exists for a reason. If the file is still being written to you don't want to read it. Even if you can there will be at least one case where your Java code thinks it has read the whole file when the CSV generation is not done yet.

In fact your code is dangerous, the file is likely closed between two shell commands that append to it, so your Java code could open and lock the file for itself while the shell script runs.

So, either start the Java code once the file is fully generated, or if the Java code is watching the file, generate the file under an temporary name, then rename to the expected name once done.

Comment: Exactly. I'm now changing my Crontab to a few minutes later, hopefully once the bash is finished, the java app will run. And renaming is another trick I will use in case this still causes problems.